# How does Firefox website able to highlight items on the navigation bar?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, manifest, browser-feature-detection

I am curious to know as when you install mozilla firefox and they open a website to let you tour the features of the browsers and from the click to call actions they are able to highlight options like the hamburger menu on the top right (they even open it), the pad lock icon near the navigation bar. Is that something they do using JS? If yes, then how?

As far as I know the browser does not gives you control via JS outside the window or viewport. Check out this url in firefox you will know what I am referring to https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/46.0.1/tracking-protection/start/?step=1

Answer (score 2):

The code is at the bottom of the page you linked to at https://www.mozilla.org/media/js/tracking-protection-tour-bundle.07309334b48d.js which utilizes the **Mozilla UITour JavaScript library** (http://bedrock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uitour.html and https://github.com/mozilla/bedrock/blob/master/docs/uitour.rst)

From the docs:

> Mozilla.UITour is a JS library that exposes an event-based Web API for
>   communicating with the Firefox browser chrome. It can be used for
>   tasks such as opening menu panels and highlighting the position of
>   buttons in the toolbar. It is supported in Firefox 29 onward.

Comment: Thanks, does similar thing is there for chrome as well?